# Component for PDF operations for preflight

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, pdf

I have did a enough search in internet, there are out few components which gives a limited functionality but I am looking for the following tasks to achieve using any single/2 components.

1. PDF is corrupted(is a valid PDF file) or not? I feel first 5 characters in header binary file is not efficient, I need this feature to be supported for all versions of PDF unlike PDFSharp supports up to 1.4 in the form of exception.
2. Page information (Color, BW/gray scale based on the color pallete)
3. Page size
4. Convert color to grayscale or grayscale to color on a specified page
5. shrink/enlarge paper size (to ensure standard paper size only)
6. PDF pages as thumbnail (don't want convert to image and display as thousands of pages expected performance wise not recommended, so any control in .NET WPF / WinForms)

Good to have OCR support feature.

Comment: *PDF is corrupted or not?* - when is a pdf to be called corrupted? Does any deviation from the pdf standard suffice?

Comment: Updated,Sorry I mean corrupted for whether the file is a valid PDF file which all pages of the file supports for printing.